# Get user_id telegram

Tags: node.js, bots, telegram

I need to know the `user_id` in order to use the [`kickChatMember`](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#kickchatmember) function.
Sometimes I'm able to retrieve it with telegram web, but if the user set a username I can't find the `user_id` anymore.

I tried with @username_to_id_bot, but I don't receive the whole `user_id`.
I'm using nodejs, and I'm using this [library](https://github.com/yagop/node-telegram-bot-api).
How can I retrieve these information?

Comment: Are you looking for the ID of a specific user? That data should be available on the `msg` param, received by a handler; `const userId = msg.from.id;`

Comment: @0stone0  I can't retrieve without bot?